# Python 3.x : How do you enable direct access to custom library functions?

Tags: python-3.x, libraries

I am new to version 3.x, also new to putting together my own custom library. Here is just a practice library I put together contained in the "example" folder: *.../site-packages/example/*

---

*Please reference below (toward the bottom) where I've provided the contents of all the files contained in the **example** library:*

- *__init__.py*
- *A.py*
- *B.py*

---

So in the python command line, the following works just fine

```
>>> import example as ex
>>> ex.a1()
a1
>>>
```

'ex.a1()' ouputs *a1* as expected.
But I'm looking for a way to access function *a1()* without having to go through the *"ex."* like.. so:

```
>>> from example import a1
>>> a1()
a1
>>>
```

Is there a way I can enable this in the *__init__.py* file? ie there are a number of functions id like to be able to access directly without having to import each and every one of them via the ***example.*** *function*

---

---

---

**__init__.py**:

```
# from   .FOLDER   import   FUNCTION
from .A import *
from .B import b1
```

**A.py**:

```
def a1():          # simply prints.. "a1"
    print('a1')

def a2():          # simply prints.. "a2"
    print('a2')
```

**B.py**:

```
def b1():          # simply prints.. "b1"
    print('b1')

def b2():          # simply prints.. "b2"
    print('b2')
```

---

---

---

Answer (score 0):

What you did with `from .A import *` is right, and it should - and does on my end - work. You import `a1` and `a2` into the namespace of `example`, and from there import it into your file.
What's your python version and interpreter? For me it works on CPython 3.10.

P.S.: You can write your module in a folder that's convenient for you, and then install it with a dynamic link: `pip install -e .`

Comment: from .B import .b1 <--

I tried this as I understood your suggestion but it didn't work. If this isn't what you meant could you perhaps spell out the full import statement for me?

from ..B import b1 <- this also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct general solution but.. I was able to get/enable the features I was looking for with the following import statement:

```
>>> from example import *
```

The solution makes sense to me however if this is not the general solution to accomplishing this, someone please speak out. Thanks!